# Laravel Notification only sends in one channel then does not detect the "toMail" method

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have a notification class called ActivityAdded, and when it is called it is supposed to notify on 2 channels, database and mail

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class ActivityAdded extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable;

public $activity;

public function __construct($activity)
{
    return $this->activity = $activity;
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database', 'mail'];
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
       'number' => $this->activity->project->id,
       'by' => $this->activity->createdBy->name,
    ];
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)->markdown('emails.activities.added',
                      [
                        'activity' => $this->activity
                      ]
    );
}
```

So now when I call this notification, it successfully adds a database entry in the notifications table, but errors on the mailing part, the error is

```
Call to undefined method App\Notifications\ActivityAdded::toMail()
```

I get the error from the jobs tab in telescope. I have no idea whats going in.

This is how im calling the notification if it matters

```
$this->project->coordinatedBy->notify(new ActivityAdded($activity));
```

Edit: Okay, here is the whole function of where its called from

```
public function createActivity()
{
    $validatedData = $this->validate();
    $validatedData['created_by_user_id'] = auth()->id();
    $validatedData['project_id'] = $this->project->id;

    $activity = Activity::create($validatedData);

    $this->project->createdBy->notify(new ActivityAdded($activity));
    $this->project->coordinatedBy->notify(new ActivityAdded($activity));

    $this->closeModalWithEvents([
      $this->emit('refreshProjectComponent')
    ]);
}
```

Another Update: It works perfectly fine on the production server, just fails on my local machine. So something else must be wrong.

Comment: Can you please show more of where you are calling if from

Comment: Added whole function code.

Comment: Do you use Laravel Queue or Supervisord?
If so, try to restart your queue use `php artisan queue:restart` and or restart your supervisord

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that this should be going into the model:

```
use App\Notifications\ActivityAdded;

...

public function activityAdded($activity) 
{
    $this->notify(new ActivityAdded($activity));
}
```

And then called from your file using the model with:

```
// get your model however you like:
$model = Model::find($id);

// then

$model->activityAdded();
```

Comment: I added that to the User model and called it like so

                $this->project->createdBy->activityAdded($activity);

Still the same result, it adds the database notification but throws 

               Call to undefined method App\Notifications\ActivityAdded::toMail()

So no email was sent.

Comment: Just curious, does it still happen if you use just the mail driver and not the database driver?

Comment: No, it does not work if I do that. But again, it works on production, just my local is broken.

Comment: Is mail setup within your .env on your local?

Comment: yes, it sends to log, other emails work fine.